# Usecase for start & stop methods of Spring Lifecycle

Tags: spring

What is a good usecase for start & stop methods of spring `Lifecycle` interface?

I see that listening & stopping to listen on a port while the application deployment is going on is a usecase for this, but this is not a good usecase. This is my reasoning. If the application is being redeployed, the context cannot be maintained as the new app might have a different code base than the current code in the context

Appreciate if someone can help me with a good usecase for `Lifecycle` interface

Answer (score 0):

Quick ones - You had app running as a Service but server restarted for Software patch/upgrade OR worst Server crashed OR you want to do fire some event at start/shutdown. 
You will restart and expect all services to start as well. You don't want to create a runbook and run them manually in some order...

Comment: I believe you are talking about `SmartLifecycle`, not `Lifecycle`